# Twin arguments and move semantic

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Assuming I have the following `foo` function:

```
Widget foo(Widget lhs, Widget rhs) {
  return lhs.bar(rhs);
}
```

I then want to use it with the same argument on both sides:

```
Widget baz(Widget w) {
  return foo(w, w);
}
```

It so happen that Widget is big and I would like to avoid having too many copies. Assuming bar is in-place, I could do the following:

```
Widget baz(Widget w) {
  return foo(std::move(w), w);
}
```

This would make only one copy. But I fear that is incorrect code as the argument passing order is unspecified in C++ and I might give a moved-from argument.

Instead I do the following:

```
Widget baz(Widget w) {
  Widget w_bis(w);
  return foo(std::move(w), std::move(w_bis));
}
```

Am I being overly cautious? Is there an easier way of achieving that?

Notes: The design of `foo` is so that I can write expressions more naturally while enjoying the benefits of copy elision. `t = foo(foo(x,y), foo(std::move(t),z))` would only perform the 3 needed copies.

Comment: I think that's the safest approach.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that the at least a rough implementation of `bar` is needed to fully help. For example, if it's non-mutating, or only mutates `*this`, we can utilize references to avoid copies.

Comment: Do you actually need to modify the `Widget` in the function? Can't you take it as const reference?

Comment: Let say, `bar` is an in-place function that I would like to transform into a more classical mathematical operator (side-effect free). I still have the benefits of copy elision this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comment `Let say, bar is an in-place function that I would like to transform into a more classical mathematical operator (side-effect free)`, let's take inspiration from how we write `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`:

Change `foo` to take `rhs` by const reference and let the compiler decide how to handle `lhs`:

```
Widget foo(Widget lhs, const Widget& rhs)
{
  return lhs.bar(rhs);
}
```

Now your original `baz` function is both correct *and* only makes one copy in the "same-object" case.